# How to serialize a CObject in Python?

Tags: python, nltk, pickle, svmlight

I've trained a SVM classifier using `NLTK` and `svmlight` python libraries and when I call `pickle.dump(my_classifier, outfile, 1)` to save my classifier, it throws this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 313, in save
    (t.__name__, obj))
    pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle 'PyCObject' object: <PyCObject object at 0xc1cbd50>
```

I read that we can't pickle a `CObject`, I didn't find a solution to save my work though :/

How could I proceed? I use python 2.7.3

For what it's worth, for those who know `NLTK`, everything works fine when I pickle other classifiers like `MaxentClassifier` or `NaiveBayesClassifier` opposed to `SvmClassifier`, I think it has something to do with `svmlight` library, but it's the first time I use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `write_model(model, filename)` from the svmlight library to save it. Maybe you can teach pickle to use that as a custom protocol for pickling.

Comment: By teaching pickle a custom protocol you mean what? modifying pickle.py?

Comment: Hans is referring to the standard pickle extension points in http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy_reg.html which is specifically for this task.

Comment: I meant maybe pickle can be configured to use custom picklers for a specific data type. However, it turns out that if you add a `__get_state__()` and `__set_state__()` method to your (subclass of the) model class it becomes pickleable. See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__

Comment: @TokenMacGuy yes, that was what I meant. Thanks for the link. Apparently there is more than one way to do it.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm kinda new to pickling things, all I know until now is `dump` and `load`. I read these links and I have no idea how to implement these methods. I don't even see this `PyCObject` because apparently it's called in `svmlight` module, which is called by `SvmClassifier`, which is called from my script. What's the best way to fix this without getting out of my script (if possible)?

Comment: Oh, and one more thing, when I tried `write_model` from svmlight, I got `Segmentation fault`...